# Parsing Issues from API call return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React component to create a line graph, fairly basic, however I am having a really hard time parsing one part of my data properly. I need to bypass the 'CVX' on the return at the start of the JSON string.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react";

const Valuations = () => {
  const [table, setTable] = useState({
    slug: [],
    lstm: []
  });

  const response = {
    method: "get",
    url: "https://marketciapi.io/api/market_lstm/CVX/detail/",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Token 5ce1831cd7a3b411ded718500cb14ed2a2f5a464"
    }
  };

  Axios(response).then((response) => {
    setTable({
      slug: response.slug,
      lstm: response.data.data
    });
  });

  const _test = table.lstm;

  return (
    <div>
      <div> {_test} </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Valuations;
```

Where the JSON response is as follows on _test:

```
{
  "CVX":
  {
    "forecast_dates": {
      "0": "2021-04-28", "1": "2021-04-29", "2": "2021-04-30", "3": "2021-05-03", "4": "2021-05-04", "5": "2021-05-05", "6": "2021-05-06", "7": "2021-05-07", "8": "2021-05-10", "9": "2021-05-11", "10": "2021-05-12", "11": "2021-05-13", "12": "2021-05-14", "13": "2021-05-17", "14": "2021-05-18", "15": "2021-05-19", "16": "2021-05-20", "17": "2021-05-21", "18": "2021-05-24", "19": "2021-05-25"
    },
    "forecast": {
      "0": 101.52, "1": 101.84, "2": 103.42, "3": 102.91, "4": 103.52, "5": 102.95, "6": 103.31, "7": 106.22, "8": 101.68, "9": 103.02, "10": 104.0, "11": 102.93, "12": 104.0, "13": 104.14, "14": 103.98, "15": 105.02, "16": 105.79, "17": 105.63, "18": 106.17, "19": 105.92
    },
    "forecast_upper": {
      "0": 103.16, "1": 103.48, "2": 105.06, "3": 104.55, "4": 105.16, "5": 104.59, "6": 104.95, "7": 107.86, "8": 103.32, "9": 104.66, "10": 105.64, "11": 104.57, "12": 105.64, "13": 105.78, "14": 105.62, "15": 106.66, "16": 107.43, "17": 107.27, "18": 107.81, "19": 107.56
    },
    "forecast_lower": {
      "0": 99.88, "1": 100.2, "2": 101.78, "3": 101.27, "4": 101.88, "5": 101.31, "6": 101.67, "7": 104.58, "8": 100.04, "9": 101.38, "10": 102.36, "11": 101.29, "12": 102.36, "13": 102.5, "14": 102.34, "15": 103.38, "16": 104.15, "17": 103.99, "18": 104.53, "19": 104.28
    }
  }
}
```

This is a CodeSandbox where I have been trying to solve the issues.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dubinsky-kn3s3?file=/src/App.js:0-665

Comment: `response.data.CVX` or `response.data.data.CVX` perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-aryabhata-0znlv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ameer, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer for others to use, would be great if you could accept :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (note, I added a useEffect with empty dependencies because your code was causing a bunch of re-renders due to updating the state on each render which subsequently caused another render and so on and so forth, now it only updates the state once)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react";

const Valuations = () => {
  const [table, setTable] = useState({
    slug: [],
    lstm: []
  });

  const response = {
    method: "get",
    url: "https://marketciapi.io/api/market_lstm/CVX/detail/",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Token 5ce1831cd7a3b411ded718500cb14ed2a2f5a464"
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios(response).then((response) => {
      setTable({
        slug: response.slug,
        lstm: response.data.data
      });
    });
  }, []);

  const _test =
    typeof table.lstm == "object"
      ? table.lstm
      : JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(table.lstm).CVX);
  console.log(typeof _test);

  return (
    <div>
      <div> {_test} </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Valuations;
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-aryabhata-0znlv?file=/src/App.js:0-840

Answer (score 0):

The fetch response to your request is a JSON document, but the value of the response.data.data property is a string. This needs to be parsed as JSON first. Replace `lstm: response.data.data` with `JSON.parse(response.data.data).CVX`.

Btw, this will break your debug output, because objects are not valid React childs. Simply stringify the value again: `{JSON.stringify(_test)}`.